# MonetDB ODBC driver memory allocation error on Windows

Tags: memory, odbc, errors, windows-server, troubleshooting

The driver is the latest from a month ago: 2014-SP2: 11.17.17, 64-bit.
Windows is Server 2012.

I have limited options to test whether earlier versions of the driver would work or this version works on other systems. I also found no other resource on this version of Windows whether ODBC works outside of Stata (ODBC Data Sources does see the database, but there is no way to test or query it).  I received little tech support about troubleshooting this error:
[image: A screen shot of how ODBC, called by Stata, does know about the database as set up, but crashes with the driver reporting error SQLSTATE=HY001]

To be clear, I noticed that [MonetDB.org](https://www.monetdb.org/downloads/Windows/Jan2014-SP2/) instructs us to install both the 64-bit and the 32-bit ODBC driver. I did that. The following screenshot shows that the MonetDB server is running, and Windows sees both the 32-bit and 64-bit data sources I set up (I only changed the names of the database to `ifn`, the rest are the defaults of MonetDB).
[image]

I understand this is not a coding issue, slightly off topic, though probably relevant for the DBA community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just released new server & driver packages (7/25/2014). I had the same issue with the old drivers but with the 7/25 release it is gone.

Comment: Also note that the issue was that Stata was passing a NULL string to the ODBC API call `SQLTables` and `SQLColumns` where the MonetDB driver wanted an empty string ("").  Some other drivers need a NULL string passed in to work (Oracle being one) so StataCorp believed this was a driver bug, but they patched the problem in Stata too.